# apache2/php container running behind reverse proxy not respecting forwarded port and proto in redirects?

Tags: php, docker, apache2, reverse-proxy, traefik

I am using a modified version of the official docker library php:7.0.30-apache image behind a reverse proxy (traefik).
The modifications include an alteration of apache2 default serving port 80 to port 1025. (openshift won't allow root operations like opening ports inside a docker container below 1024)
Now when using redirects inside the container apache2 ignores the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT` header and redirects to the correct hostname with port 1025 added.

Example: 
The application runs at `http://www.app.com` (port 80) publicly, internally at `http://app.local:1025` and when doing `header("Location: web");` it redirects to `http://www.app.com:1025/web` instead of `http://www.app.com/web`

I also noticed the following behavior: 
When using `.htaccess` files to redirect to `https` browsers display a `"too many redirects error"` because both `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT` and `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` are ignored.

What do I need to do for `.htaccess` and php `header("Location: xyz");` redirects work and respect forwarded headers behind a reverse proxy?

I do understand that this is the correct behavior for the request coming from the reverse proxy to the apache host, I just need to configure apache2 to react to the request that was made to the reverse proxy instead.

Comment: Apache doesn't itself do anything with those headers. Those headers would usually be interpreted by your web application to do redirects. If you are using OpenShift as suggested, you can also configure the Route to Redirect HTTP to HTTPS for you. That way it is handled by the haproxy. Also, why not use the OpenShift PHP S2I support?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton this has nothing to do with openshift, i just wanted to explain why i changed apaches default port. it is a general problem when running these containers behind reverse proxies.